# Having trouble validating a file over and over again

Tags: c++, file, validation

One of the things my program needs to do is validate a file using the isValid function entered by user and it will keep doing this until exit is entered and if I enter nothing but valid file names there are no problems.  But when I enter an invalid file name followed by a valid file name it still says the file is invalid and I cannot figure out why and I have tried debugging it and what not and still cannot find the problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
# include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void Open_file(string name)
{
    ifstream my_file;
    my_file.open(name.c_str());
}


bool isValid(ifstream& file, string name)
{
    if ((name.substr(name.length() - 4)) != (".htm"))
    {
        return false;
    }

    cout << file << endl;
    if (file.good())
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


string File_title(ifstream& my_file)
{
    string title;
    string line;
    size_t first_title;
    size_t second_title;
    string str;

    while((getline(my_file,line)))
    {
        str = str + line;
    }

    first_title = str.find("<title>");
    second_title = str.find("</title>");
    title = str.substr(first_title + 7, (second_title) - (first_title + 7));

    return title;
}


void Output_function(ifstream& my_file)
{

    string line;
    ifstream MyFile("titles.txt");


    string g = File_title(my_file);
    while(getline(MyFile, line))
    {
        if((g == line))
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    ofstream out_title("titles.txt", fstream::app);
    out_title << g << endl ;
}

void Clear_file()
{

    ofstream out_title("titles.txt");
    out_title << "" << endl;

}



int main()
{

    string file_name;

    while (file_name != "exit")
    {
        cout <<"please enter a HTML file name or hit 'exit' to quit and " << endl; 
        cout << "if you want to clear file please enter 'clear': ";
        getline(cin,file_name);
        ifstream my_file(file_name.c_str());
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        if(file_name == "clear")
        {
            Clear_file();
            break;

        }
        while ((isValid(my_file, file_name) == false))
        {
            cin.clear();
            cout <<"Invalid file name, please enter a valid file name: ";
            getline(cin,file_name);
            ifstream my_file(file_name.c_str());


        }

        Open_file(file_name);
        Output_function(my_file);



        my_file.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifstream my_file(file_name.c_str());
```

This doesn't replace the `my_file` you'd already created in an outer scope. It just makes a new local variable that lives for like a nanosecond.

You'll have to close then re-open the existing `my_file`, being sure to reset its error flags too.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you are using to exit the loop is flawed.

You need to check the value of `file_name` right after it is entered, not after it is processed in the `while` loop once.

You need to use something along the lines of:

```
while ((file_name = get_file_name()) != "exit")
{
   ...
}
```

where

```
std::string get_file_name()
{
   std::string file_name;
   cout <<"please enter a HTML file name or hit 'exit' to quit and " << endl; 
   cout << "if you want to clear file please enter 'clear': ";
   getline(cin,file_name);
   return file_name;
}
```

---

Other improvements:

1. The call to `cin.ignore()` is going to be a problem line since `std::getline` does not leave the newline character in the input stream. You'll have to type <kbd>Enter</kbd> one more time. You should remove it.
2. You don't need the `cin.clear()` line. You need `cin.clear()` only if an error was detected in reading from the stream -- such as when using `cin >> var;` when the input stream did not have the right data suitable for `var`.
3. You don't need to open the file if the file is not valid.
4. You don't need multiple lines `ifstream my_file(file_name.c_str());`. You only need it once, just before the call to `Output_function(my_file)`.
5. You don't need to explicitly call `my_file.close()`. The file will be closed and the end of the scope.

Here's a simplified version of `main`.

```
int main()
{
   string file_name;

   while ((file_name = get_file_name()) != "exit")
   {
      if(file_name == "clear")
      {
         Clear_file();
         break;
      }

      while ( isValid(my_file, file_name) == false )
      {
         cout <<"Invalid file name, please enter a valid file name: ";
         getline(cin,file_name);
      }

      Open_file(file_name);
      ifstream my_file(file_name.c_str());
      Output_function(my_file);
   }
}
```